# Excel 2010 delete every 57th (and 4 more) rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro code to delete every  58th row and 4 more rows after the 57th row.
i.e I need to delete row numbers 58,59,60,61 and 62nd (5 total).

I need to repeat this pattern on the entire sheet. So in effect after the macro deletes the 58,59,60,61 and 62nd rows, it needs to delete 115,116,117,118 and 119th row (difference of 57 between them 115-57 = 58).

I tried looking up on the internet, but could not find an article matching my needs. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I only know how to delete blank rows in excel (and that too was picked up from some other website). I know basic excel, but VBA programming has never been my focus.

Comment: In that case, this could be a good time to learn VBA? ;) It's very easy to write the code. I would suggest that you try it and if you get stuck, simply post the code that you tried and we will definitely help you :)

Comment: yepp..sound advice and I appreciate it. But right now, I dont have time to learn it and then fix it. Someone above me wants to put this excel in place asap. Hence I thought that such an urgency would best be answered on a forum like this.

Comment: @SiddharthRout How long can you wait before you post the answer? ;)

Comment: Have you tried Freelancer.Com?

Comment: @assylias: It depends. If Rajiv shows an effort by posting the code then my answer to your question would be "Immediate" ;)

Comment: Never mind. I will figure it out on my own. @SiddharthRout I know of free lancer and dont feel that its worth the time and effort to put it up there. I appreciate everyone's comments and whatever help you provided.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have to say that since I discovered SO I have become kind of an addict and although I know you are right I find it hard not to post the 4 lines code... cf: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you

Comment: @Rajiv Varma: See my last comment to assylias ;)

Comment: @assylias: :) Even I am addicted to forums like SO. But for different reasons. I never answer question for points ;) Points can't buy you Harley Davidson. Can it? ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry - I could not not do it. You can downvote my answer, I deserve it.

Comment: @assylias: Nah I won't downvote (haven't done it till date) and that too for such frivolous things ;) Enjoy your points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you post a question, you would get better attention and feedback if at least you tried something, anything really. A good first step is to run the macro recorder in Excel, delete a few rows and check the code that has been generated. From there, the final solution is not very far.

```
Sub deleteRows()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxRow As Long

    maxRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 58 To maxRow Step 52 'Step 52, not 57, because we delete 5 rows each time
        Range(Rows(i), Rows(i + 4)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @assylias. Like I said, I would have figured this out on my own, but would have taken longer than usual to do it. I will keep your suggestion in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For a non-code method you could choose a blank column beside your data and try these steps:

- Select the range e.g. A57:A60 and enter `X` with ctrl+enter to fill the cells
- Select the repeating range e.g. A1:A60, and fill down to the end of the data (or use copy/paste)
- Press Ctrl+Shift+\ to select all the `X`'s (goto special... column differences or use autofilter)
- Choose Delete > Sheet Rows from the Cells section of the Home Tab

You're done. This also preserves the undo stack so you can backtrack if required.